# Do I change my brakes, because I'm trimming my rotors?

Tags: brake-rotor

I'm resurfacing/trimming my rotors, do I have to replace my brake pads too?

Answer (score 3):

Yes you should. The price of new pads (in most cases) is small $$. This will get you fresh mating surfaces on both sides. If you don't, you run the risk of screwing up your fresh cut on the old rotors. Don't forget to correctly bed the new brakes after installation or you run the risk of being back at square one.

Comment: Plus the old pads will have worn themselves into the old shape of the disks (i.e. matched the old wear pattern), so won't brake effectively against the new surfaces. As Paul says, new pads are cheap...

Answer (score 0):

Pads and rotors should be considered a consumerable item. Forget about re-grinding the rotors. If you are on to your second set of pads on your rotors, drag your thumb nail across their surface. If your nail can feel any grooving or catching, change the rotors and the pads.